# How to change query result without using pivot functions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which shows number of cheap and expensive orders for a date:

```
 SELECT   od1.date,
  (SELECT COUNT(  od2.id) FROM myorders od2
    INNER JOIN myproducts ON od2.product_id = myproducts.id
  WHERE  od2.date = od1.date
         AND myproducts.price BETWEEN 500 AND 2000
         ) cheap_orders,
  (SELECT SUM(myproducts.price)
   FROM myorders od2
     INNER JOIN myproducts ON od2.product_id = myproducts.id
   WHERE od2.date = od1.date
         AND myproducts.price BETWEEN 500 AND 2000
 ) sum_ch_o,
  (SELECT COUNT(  od2.id) FROM myorders od2
    INNER JOIN myproducts ON od2.product_id = myproducts.id
  WHERE  od2.date = od1.date
         AND myproducts.price > 2000
         ) expensive_orders,
  (SELECT SUM(myproducts.price)
   FROM myorders od2
     INNER JOIN myproducts ON od2.product_id = myproducts.id
   WHERE od2.date = od1.date
         AND myproducts.price > 2000

 ) sum_exp_o

FROM myorders od1
GROUP BY od1.date
```

It returns me a table:

```
date        cheap_orders  sum_ch_o  expensive_orders  sum_exp_o
2018-06-06  0             0         1                 4000
2018-06-04  2             3100      0                 0 
2018-06-07  1             780       3                 28000
2018-06-05  1             560       4                 15500
```

How can I modify my query to get another view of this table:

```
date        order_cat      quantity      sum  
2018-06-06  cheap          0             0
2018-06-06  expensive      1             4000
2018-06-04  cheap          2             3100
2018-06-04  expensive      0             0
2018-06-07  cheap          1             780
2018-06-07  expensive      3             28000
```

Comment: Skip the subqueries, do a left join instead. Use case expressions to conditional aggregation.

Comment: It would be lot simpler if you didn’t need the zero rows. Can you live without them?

Comment: "Use case expressions to conditional aggregation"  - it helped me. Thanks to jarl!